# Submitting form to PHP file after javascript validation

Tags: javascript, php, html

For a contact form I have added basic validation, however when trying to submit the form to a PHP file in order to actually send an email - the form is refusing to submit I have no idea as to why and I have no idea how to fix it

I have made the button type="submit" as well as making the form action="contactform.php" none have heeded any results

Below I have added the contact form,javascript file in question as well as the PHP file I'm trying to send it to

Of course I cannot use my details for PHPMailer so you will need to add your own

Thanks

HTML - contact_us.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../img/logo.png">
        <!-- Page Title -->
        <title>LNEM - Womens</title>
    
        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/contact.css"/>
    
        <!-- Icon CSS -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons+Outlined" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="contact-form">
            <div class="first-container">
                <div class="info-container">
                    <div>
                        <h3>Postal Address</h3>
                        <p>Unit 82 <br> Shingshowers Road <br> Deeblock Steppers Estate <br> Broward County <br> BR19 0DW</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Contact Email</h3>
                        <p>support@lnem.co.uk</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Telephone</h3>
                        <p>+44 XXXX XXXXXX</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="second-container">
                <h2>CONTACT US</h2>
                
                <form id="contact_form" method="post" name="ContactForm" >
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input id="contact_name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="John Doe">
                        <small></small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Email</label>
                        <input id="contact_email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
                        <small></small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Subject</label>
                        <input id="contact_subject" name="subject" type="text" placeholder="Order">
                        <small></small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message">Message</label>
                        <textarea id="contact_message" name="message" type="text" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                        <small></small>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" >Send Message</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="../js/validation/contactval.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

PHP File - contactform.php

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require '../phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require '../phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require '../phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $mailFrom = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $mailTo = "";
    $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
    $txt = "You have recieved an e-mail from ".$name.".\n\n".$message;
    
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    $mail-> isSMTP();
    $mail ->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail -> SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail ->Username = '';
    $mail ->Password = '';

    $mail ->setFrom($mailFrom);
    $mail ->addAddress($mailTo);
    $mail ->isHTML(true);
    $mail ->Subject = $subject;
    $mail ->Body = $txt;
    $mail ->send();

    header('Location: contact_us.php?success');
}
else{
    header('Location: contact_us.php');
}

?>
```

Javascript

```
const ContactName = document.querySelector('#contact_name');
const ContactEmail = document.querySelector('#contact_email');
const ContactSubject = document.querySelector('#contact_subject');
const ContactMessage = document.querySelector('#contact_message');

const ContactForm = document.querySelector('#contact_form');
const submitform  = document.getElementById('contact_form');


const checkContactName = () => {

    let valid = false;

    const min = 1,
        max = 50;

    const c_name = ContactName.value.trim();

    if (!isRequired(c_name)) {
        showError(ContactName, 'Name cannot be blank.');
    } else if (!isBetween(c_name.length, min, max)) {
        showError(ContactName, `Name must be between ${min} and ${max} characters.`)
    } else {
        showSuccess(ContactName);
        valid = true;
    }
    return valid;
};


const checkContactEmail = () => {
    let valid = false;
    const c_email = ContactEmail.value.trim();
    if (!isRequired(c_email)) {
        showError(ContactEmail, 'Email cannot be blank.');
    } else if (!isEmailValid(c_email)) {
        showError(ContactEmail, 'Email is not valid.')
    } else {
        showSuccess(ContactEmail);
        valid = true;
    }
    return valid;
};

const checkContactSubject = () => {

    let valid = false;

    const min = 2,
        max = 50;

    const c_subject = ContactSubject.value.trim();

    if (!isRequired(c_subject)) {
        showError(ContactSubject, 'Message cannot be blank.');
    } else if (!isBetween(c_subject.length, min, max)) {
        showError(ContactSubject, `Message must be between ${min} and ${max} characters.`)
    } else {
        showSuccess(ContactSubject);
        valid = true;
    }
    return valid;
};


const checkContactMessage = () => {

    let valid = false;

    const min = 2,
        max = 500;

    const c_message = ContactMessage.value.trim();

    if (!isRequired(c_message)) {
        showError(ContactMessage, 'Message cannot be blank.');
    } else if (!isBetween(c_message.length, min, max)) {
        showError(ContactMessage, `Message must be between ${min} and ${max} characters.`)
    } else {
        showSuccess(ContactMessage);
        valid = true;
    }
    return valid;
};


const isEmailValid = (c_email) => {
    const re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(c_email);
};



const isRequired = value => value === '' ? false : true;
const isBetween = (length, min, max) => length < min || length > max ? false : true;


const showError = (input, message) => {
    // get the form-field element
    const formField = input.parentElement;

    // show the error message
    const error = formField.querySelector('small');
    error.textContent = message;
};

const showSuccess = (input) => {
    // get the form-field element
    const formField = input.parentElement;

    // hide the error message
    const error = formField.querySelector('small');
    error.textContent = '';
}

function validateForm(){
    ContactForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        // prevent the form from submitting
        e.preventDefault();
    
        // validate fields
        let isNameValid = checkContactName(),
            isEmailValid = checkContactEmail();
            isSubjectValid = checkContactSubject();
            isMessageValid = checkContactMessage();
    
        let isFormValid = isNameValid &&
            isEmailValid && isSubjectValid &&
            isMessageValid;
    
        // submit to the server if the form is valid --> this is where I think code needs to be added
        if (isFormValid) {
        }
    });
}



const c_debounce = (fn, delay = 500) => {
    let timeoutId;
    return (...args) => {
        // cancel the previous timer
        if (timeoutId) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        }
        // setup a new timer
        timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            fn.apply(null, args)
        }, delay);
    };
};

ContactForm.addEventListener('input', c_debounce(function (e) {
    switch (e.target.id) {
        case 'contact_name':
            checkContactName();
            break;
        case 'contact_email':
            checkContactEmail();
            break;
        case 'contact_subject':
            checkContactSubject();
            break;
        case 'contact_message':
            checkContactMessage();
            break;
    }
}));
```

Comment: What exactly does "refusing to submit" mean? What happens? Are there errors in  the browser console?

Comment: While I don't see you attaching the submit listener (i.e. `validateForm()` is never called), I presume your issue is the premature call `evt.preventDefault()`. Try calling it only if the form is invalid. Make sure to add the `action` attribute.

Comment: @Pointy - When I enter information and press the submit button nothing happens there are no errors that popup, the JavaScript validation messages disappear when I enter correctly formatted info so I want it to then perform the form action when I do press "send message"

Answer (score 0):

add action="contactform.php" in your form tag

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).